# Attributing input importance in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, feature-selection

Is there a way to find the importance of the input using Keras? I have a CNN architecture where the input is a matrix (every row contains different information, as if every row was a different feature. I could change rows for columns if it was necessary, as I am the one building the matrix). Since every row is considered as a different feature, I wonder if there could be a way to see which rows are of more importance to the CNN to perform the classification. I know that for some machine learning algorithms, such as Trees or Boosting Algorithms, you can check the importance the algorithm is giving to the features, so I would like to do the same but with CNN and Keras. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are various visualisation libraries, where you can use a graph to check how your inputs correlate to each other.
(link to seaborn documenation - https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

I recommend using seaborn or Matplotlib.